# Xamarin SQLite connection error

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

After setting the DependencyService up so I could get the application root file for iOS and Android. But I get an error as soon as I try to build up a connection. The path itself is correct, I checked that. Here's the code:

```
public class Queries
{
    private string folder = DependencyService.Get<IFileSystemService>().GetAppDataFolder();
    
    public bool createDataBase()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(folder, "Test.db")))
            {
                connection.CreateTable<Posten>();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The exception happens in the using and is the following:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception. occurred

I really don't know why it is doing this. I already did it like this in an all Android application and it worked without any issues.

Comment: Do not post images. Code is made of text, it is a lot easier for you to do and for us to read if you use a simply copy/paste.

Comment: But I wanted to show the Exception message too... should I remove the picture and just write code?

Comment: There is a `Copy Details` link button in the exception window.

Comment: Ok i changed it

Comment: There is more to the exception than that. There should be a stack trace and possibly (probably) an inner exception.

Comment: I think the error is not SQLite, but what you're passing to it. What gets returned from `GetAppDataFolder` exactly?

Comment: The path gets returned there. I am using an android device. The path is correct.
and what do you need from my stack?

Comment: To debug a problem, you want to know everything you can. You should get used to inspecting the entire exception and not just the `Message`.

Comment: no I was just intrested in knowing what he was looking for so i could remember it next time. anyways i found the problem. i didn't have sqlite in the nuget packages of the android project ;____; I wasted a whole day on this